# Determine column value dynamically based on another table column in MySQL statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Is there a way to perform a query in MySQL like this one in pseudo code:

```
INSERT INTO table_a(a, b, c) SELECT table_b.a, table_b.b, IF (table_b.c <100) 500 else 1000 WHERE ...
```

I know I can make two separate queries as a transaction but I want to know if there's a way to insert a value for a column based on another column from another table without going over the records twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.
You can use the `CASE` construct:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (a, b, c) 
SELECT table_b.a, table_b.b, CASE WHEN table_b.c < 100 THEN 500 else 1000 END
FROM   table_b
WHERE  ...
```